# java - convert millisecond to localtime

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to convert millisecond value to local time
For example, we have this value 1601981597562 when I convert it to Date in UTC it gives me the day will be Oct 10 but in local time it should be Oct 11

```
new DateTime(1601981597562)
```

[image]

[Ref](https://currentmillis.com/)

My question whats the way to convert that timestamp to the local time to be Oct 11 instead of Oct 10

Comment: What is your problem ? It seems ok to me.

Comment: What timezone are you in?  Have you told your program that?

Comment: my timezone is Africa_Egypt but the server is Los Angeles

Comment: Do you have to use Joda Time or can you use `java.time` as well?

Comment: I prefer Joda time

Comment: `new DateTime(1602367200000L, DateTimeZone.forID("Egypt"))` returns a `DateTime` that prints as `2020-10-11T00:00:00.000+02:00`. As [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225724/java-convert-millisecond-to-localtime#comment113571329_64225724) implied, you can only get the desired "local" date/time, if you define what "local" means.

Comment: yea but I need a dynamic timezone means it will be determined on run time depending on user browser timezone

Answer (score 2):

You should use date for this .
Add these codes into your activity.

```
String localTime = String.valueOf(new Date(timeMillis));
```

Comment: Using `java.util.Date` instead of Joda Time classes appears like a downgrade...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Date** to convert Epoch to UTC like so:

```
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new Date(epoch);
System.out.println(date);
```

Ensure that **Date** is *java.util.Date*

Comment: Unfortunately, `Date` and most of its related classes are deprecated so its use is highly discouraged.  Solutions using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package are preferred.